# Cannot link to libclang in OSX High Sierra

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm-clang, libclang

I have installed llvm and clang through brew.

When I compile a program with the header file "clang-c/Index.h", I get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_clang_createIndex", referenced from:
  _main in t-c9baef.o
....
```

Here is the command I used for compiling my program:

```
CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include make prog
```

I am using OSX High Sierra.

Comment: Could you also share your Makefile? You need to provide additional linker flag to link against libclang such as `-lclang`, also you need to teach clang where to look for this library, such as `-L/path/to/libclang/dylib`.

Comment: I am not using any specific makefile, I am just using the make command.

I updated my command: [CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ LDFLAGS=“-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.1/lib/libclang.dylib” CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include make t]


But still it does not work. I get -L/path/to/lobclang.dylib does not exist.

when I put -lclang I get the same error. Where should I put it exactly?

Comment: -L should point to a directory, not to the actual file

Comment: Thanks @AlexDenisov I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue.

The command I used for building is:

```
CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ \
LDFLAGS+='-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.1/lib -lclang' \
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include \
make myprog
```

I had to link against the libclang.dylib and add -lclang